# Enable offline data access with angularfire2

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, ionic2, angularfire2

I'm developing a Firebase based application using Ionic2 and Angularfire2. Does anybody know if its possible to `setPersistenceEnabled(true)` to allow for offline application use?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Firebase offline capabilities in ionic / cordova](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40448471/firebase-offline-capabilities-in-ionic-cordova)

Comment: Check the following answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44422881/988434

Comment: Did you get this to work with the realtime DB?

Answer (score 2):

All Firebase SDKs handle intermittent connectivity loss, by keeping a cache of active data in memory and keeping a queue of pending writes.

Native mobile SDKs (for iOS and Android) have the ability to persist the cache and queue to disk, so that it survives app restarts. The web SDK does not have this ability.

Comment: Is this capability planned? Is there some inherent limitation in the web SDK / platform, preventing this?